# Get Context in a Service

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

Is there any reliable way to get a `Context` from a `Service`?

I want to register a broadcast receiver for `ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED` but I don't need my app to always get this information, so I don't put it in the `Manifest`.

However, I can't have the broadcast receiver be killed by the GC when I need this information so I'm registering the broadcast receiver in a `Service`.

Hence, I need a `Context` to to call `registerReceiver()`.
 When I no longer need the `ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED` I **unregister** it.

Any tips?

Answer (score 866, accepted):

[Service](http://d.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) is a [Context](http://d.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html)

Comment: I had this problem, but it turned out that it was the worker thread that had no context. I solved it my passing a context when constructing the thread.

Comment: Note: The context within the service will not be visible until onStart or onStartCommand in services: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619917/how-to-get-context-in-android-service-class

Answer (score 76):

`Service` extends `ContextWrapper` which extends `Context`. Hence the `Service` is a `Context`.
Use `'this'` keyword in the service.

Answer (score 35):

1. `Service` extends `ContextWrapper`
2. `ContextWrapper` extends `Context`

So....

```
Context context = this;
```

(in Service or Activity Class)

Answer (score 12):

just in case someone is getting `NullPointerException`, you need to get the context inside `onCreate().`

`Service` is a `Context`, so do this:

```
private Context context;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    context = this;
}
```

Note:

Read: "Do not place Android context classes in static fields; this is a memory leak (and also breaks Instant Run)" Do you know what context classes are? Activity is one of them, and you should not store Activity as a static field, (or it will leak memory). However, you can store Context (as long as it is the application context) as a static field, since it outlives everything.

Answer (score 8):

Since `Service` is a `Context`, the variable context must be `this`:

```
DataBaseManager dbm = Utils.getDataManager(this);
```

Answer (score 5):

As **Service** is already a **Context** itself

you can even get it through:

```
Context mContext = this;
```

OR

```
Context mContext = [class name].this;  //[] only specify the class name
// mContext = JobServiceSchedule.this;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want service context then use `this` keyword. if you want activity context you can access that by using by making static variable like this

```
public static Context context;
```

in the activity `onCreate()`

```
context=this;
```

now you can access that context inside the service

Comment: Read: "Do not place Android context classes in static fields; this is a memory leak (and also breaks Instant Run)" Do you know what context classes are? Activity is one of them, and you should not store Activity as a static field, (or it will leak memory). However, you can store Context (as long as it is the application context) as a static field, since it outlives everything.