# How to get context in android Service class

Tags: android, android-service

I am getting the following error when i try to read a XML file from the memory and into an object. Seems like problem with getting the Context. Can anyone tell me whats wrong with my code?

**Code:**

```
public class WifiScanning extends Service {

private static final String TAG = "WifiScanning";
private Timer timer;
public int refreshRate;

public WifiScanning() {
    super();
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance(); 
    SAXParser sp;
    XMLReader xr = null; 
    DataHandler dataHandler = null;
    try {
        sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        xr = sp.getXMLReader();
        dataHandler = new DataHandler(); 
        xr.setContentHandler(dataHandler); 


        xr.parse(new InputSource(this.openFileInput("config.xml")));
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    config = dataHandler.getConfig();
    refreshRate = Integer.parseInt(config.getMapRefreshRate());
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

private TimerTask updateTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Timer task doing work");
    }
};

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.i(TAG, "Service creating");

    timer = new Timer("TweetCollectorTimer");
    Log.i(TAG, "Refresh Rate: "+ String.valueOf(refreshRate));
    timer.schedule(updateTask, 0, 3000L);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i(TAG, "Service destroying");

    if (timer != null){
        timer.cancel();
        timer.purge();
        timer = null;
    }
}

public void onStop() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Service destroying");
    if (timer != null){
        timer.cancel();
        timer.purge();
        timer = null;
    }
}
}
```

**LogCat:**

```
10-01 11:08:49.804: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21514): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service android.wps.WifiScanning: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-01 11:08:49.804: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21514):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2764)
10-01 11:08:49.804: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21514):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3200(ActivityThread.java:119)
10-01 11:08:49.804: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21514):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1917)
10-01 11:08:49.804: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21514):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-01 11:08:49.804: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21514):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-01 11:08:49.804: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21514):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
10-01 11:08:49.804: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21514):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-01 11:08:49.804: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21514):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-01 11:08:49.804: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21514):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
10-01 11:08:49.804: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21514):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
10-01 11:08:49.804: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21514):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-01 11:08:49.804: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21514): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-01 11:08:49.804: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21514):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileInput(ContextWrapper.java:152)
10-01 11:08:49.804: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21514):     at android.wps.WifiScanning.<init>(WifiScanning.java:52)
10-01 11:08:49.804: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21514):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
10-01 11:08:49.804: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21514):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1479)
10-01 11:08:49.804: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21514):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2761)
10-01 11:08:49.804: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21514):     ... 10 more
```

Comment: Did you try IntentService. It is much easier to handle. Btw, Service extends Context.

Comment: but can this class read file from the memory?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should do this not in the constructor, but only between (inclusive) onCreate() and onDestroy().

Comment: u mean the portion of coding for retrieving the xml file should be between onCreate() and onDestroy()?

Comment: I mean, that for Android system, Activities and Services live not between call of constructor and garbage collection, but their live starts from call onCreate() and finishes after call onDestroy(). I mean, that you can do any actions/interactions with services in the method onCreate() or later, before onDestroy(). Constructor of service is called before onCreate().

Comment: thanks for telling me that. my code works after i shifted the codes in the constructor to onCreat().

Comment: Also, you may read XML files, load sounds and so on in onBind(), onStart(), onUnbind() (although I can't imagine such situation), onRebind() or any other method (also self-made) occured after onCreate(). For example, I bind with service and after binding I call self-made method loadSounds() - the context isn't null, so service works.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a service you are supposed to write that code in [onStartCommand](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29), not in the constructor

Comment: does startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), WifiScanning.class)); have something to do with onStartCommand?

Comment: Yes. onStartCommand() is called by the system every time a client explicitly starts the service using startService()

Comment: so you mean i can retrieved context from the intent that is pass to the Servce when client explicitly starts the service?

Comment: No, since the Intent lives outside of the Context. Why do you need the context? What is on line 52 of WifiScanning.java?

Comment: cause i need it to read data from the XML that i store in the memory. line 52, public void onCreate()?