# Can I get data from shared preferences inside a service?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-service, android-2.2-froyo

I'm developing an android application. I'm using android 2.2

In my application I am capturing GPS data and sending it to service with the 1 hour time interval. If user exits from application it's also working (it is required).

I'm using 2 services (User defined), one for capturing GPS data and other for sending to the server.

Here my doubt

- In service, can we use shared preferences.
- If we store any data in shared preferences in any activity of the application, will we be able to use that data in service with the help of shared preferences?

Comment: Best answer found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446221/get-context-in-a-service?lq=1

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I find the solution.

Inside a service we call the following method to get the shared preferences

```
myapp.bmodel.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("myPrefs_capture_gps_per_hour", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

In the above code **myapp** is a object of the application class which is derived from **Application**

Answer (score 47):

You can access the default shared preferences instance, which is shared across all your `Activity` and `Service` classes, by calling [`PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context context)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getDefaultSharedPreferences%28android.content.Context%29):

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

This is great for storing simple primitives (like booleans) or serializable objects. However, if you're capturing a lot of location data, you might consider using a SQLite database instead.

Comment: This answer combined with this: The context within the service will not be visible until onStart or onStartCommand in services: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619917/how-to-get-context-in-android-service-class solved this for me.

Comment: You can always pass in the result of the service's `getApplicationContext()` method instead.

Comment: @twaddington So if we use `getSharedPreferences(String, Context)` the preferences would not be shared?

Comment: @twaddington: I also use the shared preference across my activity and services like         mPrefsRead = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
. But sometimes, I get the default values from the preferences like if I write mPrefsWrite.putBoolean(KEY, true) but I get false when reading like mPrefsRead.getBoolean(KEY_LOGIN_STATUS, false);. I also confirmed that the value is not set false anywhere. My app and services run as different processes, which leads to get default values from preferences as told in some SO answers. Is it possible to resolve this using your answer.

Comment: This is the proper answer Thanks to twaddington and for example in MyService Class and Method below:

@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String email = preferences.getString("email_address", "default@google.com");
        mythread = new MyThread(email);
        Toast.makeText(this, email, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

Answer (score 8):

You need a context to get access to shared preferences. The best way is to create `MyApplication` as a descendant of `Application` class, instantiate there the  `preferences` and use them in the rest of your application as `MyApplication.preferences`:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    public static SharedPreferences preferences;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        preferences = getSharedPreferences( getPackageName() + "_preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

For example, if you need access to your preferences somewhere else, you may call this to read preferences:

```
String str = MyApplication.preferences.getString( KEY, DEFAULT );
```

Or you may call this to save something to the preferences:

```
MyApplication.preferences.edit().putString( KEY, VALUE ).commit();
```

(don't forget to call `commit()` after adding or changing preferences!)

Comment: This would technically work, but why wouldn't you just use the provided `PreferenceManager#getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context context);` static method? That's exactly what it's for.

Comment: @twaddington you should read more carefully. my answer allows access to preferences when `context` is **not** available.

Comment: Sure, but he's specifically asking about using shared preferences in an `Activity` and a `Service`, both of which have a `Context` available.

Comment: It shouldn't matter which context you provide, `getDefaultSharedPreferences` should always return the same `SharedPreference` instance.

Comment: and does MyApplication need to be created inside variable in any activities or something?

Comment: @gumuruh no, it's a separate file, MyApplication.java (or .kt).

Comment: okay. I made that file now and so when the onCreate() method was called ?

Answer (score 8):

Yes Shivkumar, you can use your share preferences in any kind of services as normal as you are using in your Activity.

same like

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("<PrefName>",
            MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: Simple! Similarly for getResources, getString, etc... The IntentService class inherits from Context.

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to create instance of `SharedPreference`:

Case 1:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = activity.getSharedPreferences("<PrefName>", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Case 2:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

Notice if you create a preference with the same name (case 1) or same context (case 2) even at different places, it's still the same, and can share data, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

In a Service, I would use

```
  SharedPreferences sharedPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```