# getApplicationContext() throws nullpointexception

Tags: java, android, android-service

I'm trying to access SharedPreferences in a service.

```
public class LocationService extends Service implements 
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, 
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, 
    LocationListener {

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

    ...
```

But I get this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service us.keithirwin.myapp.LocationService: java.lang.NullPointerException
        ...
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:101)
        at us.keithirwin.myapp.LocationService.<init>(LocationService.java:31)
        ...
```

LocationService.java:31 refers to `Context context = getApplicationContext();`.

I used to use `this` as context, i.e

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

That line started coming up null also.  My research led me to use `getApplicationContext()` as my context.  But it's nulls every way I turn.

`LocationService.<init>` sounds like the constructor.  Other posts seem to say that I can't call preferences there.  However, if I try to create sharedPref in onCreate, it's only available in that method.  Is there some way to have the preferences available throughout the service?

Comment: override onCreate and move it into it

Comment: I'd like to know why this question was downvoted.  According to [the faq](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): `if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `LocationService.<init>` sounds like the constructor.

Actually, it's an initializer for a data member.

> However, if I try to create sharedPref in onCreate, it's only available in that method.

You are welcome to declare the data member outside of `onCreate()`. You cannot *initialize* the data member until inside `onCreate()`:

```
public class LocationService extends Service {
  private SharedPreferences sharedPref;

  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    sharedPref=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
  }

  // other cool stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
```

with

```
Context ctx = this;
```

Comment: Then `getDefaultSharedPreferences` throws nullpointerexception

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558550/can-i-get-data-from-shared-preferences-inside-a-service

Answer (score 1):

ok, it's because this class (Service in this question) has not instantiated, so "this" is null. Also, I found a interesting question just like yours [Can "this" ever be null in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789528/can-this-ever-be-null-in-java). It might help

I think you should do this line:
    sharedPref=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
after onCreate() as CommonWare suggested.

Answer (score 0):

`Service` is `Context`. `Service` extends `ContextWrapper`  and  `ContextWrapper` extends `Context` therefore all you have to do is :

```
Context context = this;
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Then `getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)` throws nullpointerexception

Comment: override onCreate and use it or you have to use it in the onStartCommand