# Change integer value from another Activity

Tags: java, android

I want change a value from another activity like this

Main_activity.java

```
...
long notify_interval = 1000; //ms
...
```

But, In another activity, called system.java, I have this code

```
btn_normal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Main_activity.notify_interval = 1000; // HERE <<--
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Interval changed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

But isn't working, someone tells me that this way never will work. So, what should I do?

--------- UPDATE ---------

Hello, with this trick, I'm able to change long value between activities

```
 public static long notify_interval = 1000;
```

But, I'm using AlarmManager, when I close the app, instead of using the custom notify_interval that I set, the system is using the default value (1000). So, what should I do to fix it?

Comment: Static variables are not the way to share values

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do, there are tons of ways to share data between activities. You could use an SQLite Database, SharedPreferences, or just hold the data in the MainActivity and send via a Bundle in the Intent.

Comment: @escapesequence I'm getting problems with this method in this link that you mentioned. Sorry

Comment: The notify_internal is being called by several functions, so, I believe that it's more complex than I think, idk...

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm not able to use data-storage since I'm using Service as extends, I believe.

Comment: You only need a Context to use SharedPreferences. A Service is a Context object

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558550/can-i-get-data-from-shared-preferences-inside-a-service

Comment: However, you still need to **tell** the MainActivity that the value has changed. (Like a BroadcastReceiver)

Answer (score 1):

If u need to do it in real-time, make `interface` and make activity implement it then pass it where u are updating value and call method that updates value in activity

else u need to add extra to [intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

another way is to use [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid) or [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).

Answer (score 1):

You can use static variable to do that.

```
public static long notify_interval = 1000;
```

On second activity use

```
btn_normal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Main_activity.notify_interval = 1000; // HERE <<--
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Interval changed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Its worked fine.

Comment: Hello! I already tried it, but the notify_interval is not being updated. Maybe it is being always used in a process.

Comment: You take notify_interval as static variable ?

Comment: Yes, I already changed

Comment: can i have your main_activity code here.

Comment: Here you go: https://pastebin.com/5N2w2wFx

Comment: and second activity also

Comment: https://pastebin.com/g9U7nHUk

Comment: you want to change mTimer.schedule(new TimerTaskToGetLocation(),5,notify_interval); interval time right.

Comment: Yes, change it!

Comment: So my friend the mTimer.schedule was in onCreate method, which run only once. So if you change the value of notify_interval not worked over here.

Comment: you need to restart service after setting value to notify_interval.

Comment: Do you know how?

Comment: create method on main_activity called restartService(){stopService(new Intent(this, GoogleService.class)); startService(new Intent(this, GoogleService.class)); } and called this every time after setting notify_interval

Comment: It's working, but I'm using AlarmManager, and in background mode, he's using the default notify_interval value, not the value that I changed. What should I do to solve it?