# Android: Create a file from a Service

Tags: android, android-service, android-file

I have been successfully able to create files in my apps local directory using the below code

```
    File appDir = new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(null), "my_folder");
    if (!appDir.exists())
    {
        boolean result = appDir.mkdir();
        if (!result) {
            Log.i(Util.TAG, LOG_LABEL
                    + "::  Unable to create \"my_folder\" Directory : "
                    + appDir.getAbsolutePath()
                    + "  Directory already exists !");
        }
    }


    File HTMLFile = new File(appDir,"html.txt");
```

But now when I tried to do the same from a service, the file was not being created, I even checked using 'HTMLFile.exists()' and it says the file does not exist.

My question is, Is it actually possible to create files from a service? or am I missing something here.

Comment: Are you passing your activity context to your service? And then using `context.getExternalFilesDir`?

Comment: @filespl: Do we need to pass context to the service? I read that Service has its own context. source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446221/get-context-in-a-service

Comment: I doubt into my answer now :) I thought this could be related to different permissions on the file (or different dir being returned).

Comment: @filespl: I was able to create a file now using
        
            HTMLFile.createNewFile(); I dindn't have to do this previously though.

Comment: could you answer your own question with the code..

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to write to the storage of your android: by the help of the following methods

1. Make sure you provide uses permission to write and read from storage in manifest file.
2. I have used this code:

   ```
   private File newFile;

   public ListenNotification() {
           Log.d("Service","InConstrutor");
   newFile=newFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"NotificationFromService");

           if(!newFile.exists()){
               Log.d("Service","Created");
               newFile.mkdir();
           }
           else{
               Log.d("Service","Existed");
           }
       }
   File HTMLFile = new File(newFile,"html.txt");
   ```