# Pass context to service with putExtra

Tags: java, android, android-intent, service

How to pass `context` to a service with `putExtra`?

The problem is : `android.os.Application` cannot be cast to `java.io.Serializable`

How to solve this problem?

```
// main activity
public void btnGetLocate() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Sleeper.class); 
    intent.putExtra("context", (Serializable) getApplicationContext());
    startService(intent);
}

// another file
public class MyService extends IntentService {
    public Sleeper() {
        super("MyService"); 
    }

    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) { 
        Context context = (Context) intent.getExtras().getSerializable("context"); // make Error, main problem
        MyClass mc = new MyClass(context);  
        ...
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "destroyed"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
    } 
}
```

Comment: why do you want to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Context in a Service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446221/get-context-in-a-service)

Comment: @pskink because gps locator

Comment: Try another solution

Comment: please write example

Comment: @2Dee I check it, but make fatal error.

Comment: GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(context); 
 
  // check if GPS enabled
  if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
   
   
   
   double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
   double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

   // \n is for new line
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your  Location - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: "+ longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  } else {
   // can't get location
   // GPS or Network is not enabled
   // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
   gps.showSettingsAlert();
  }

Comment: Please edit the question to provide additional code. It's difficult to read in comments.

Answer (score 8):

You cannot do that, nor do you need to. Not only is `Service` a `Context`, but `Service` can call `getApplicationContext()` to get the `Application` object if that is what you truly need. Do not pass in extras things that the service can get on its own.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it (use context as extra) because this class *Application* doesn't implements *Serializable* interface.

The easy way to do it is display a dialog with title *Getting location..." and do the location request inside current activity. Then, when you get the location, dismiss the dialog.

You can follow this [Google tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html), which uses Google Play Services, to get *location* in an easy way.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You should bound/bind `Service` - in that case you'll be able to have reference to `Service` object in your `Activity`. Using those reference it's pretty easy to set/send `Context`.

[See here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)