# Which Context to call startService

Tags: android, android-context

I have code in Activity that uses getApplication().bindService() or just bindService().
Is one preferable over another. Considering that Activity has lifecycles, under what scenario would an Application context be used to start/bind to a service.

Comment: Check this answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446221/get-context-in-a-service) , it has some clarification about the 2 concepts.

Answer (score 6):

For *binding* to a service from an activity, use the `Application` context (`getApplication()`). That is because the binding itself represents state that needs to be handled as part of configuration change processing (e.g., via `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`). One activity instance might bind, but then you might not unbind until after a configuration change. Using the `Activity` as the `Context` for `bindService()` *might* introduce a memory leak (new activity holds an indirect reference back to the original activity that bound to the service).

However, *starting* a service from an activity involves no framework-imposed state in the activity. Hence, starting the service using `startService()` on the activity itself should be fine.

Comment: honestly, i never saw any `Activity` that calls `bindService` on the `Application` context, `bind` / `unbind` requests should be paired so there is no chance for a leak...

Comment: @pskink: If you unbind from the old activity, the service may shut down before you get a chance to bind again from the new activity, as part of a configuration change. Now, if you're sure that something else is keeping the service running (e.g., it's both bound and started), perhaps that is not an issue.