# how to haveinstance of activity converted to gson

Tags: android, json, gson

In the below code, I am trying to convert activity to a JSON object so I can pass such an object to a service via intent. please refer to the code posted in code_1 and code_2 sections. However, when the app is executed, I receive
the below-posted error.

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class android.content.res.ColorStateList declares multiple JSON fields named mChangingConfigurations
```

please let me know why I receive such error and how to solve it.

**code_1**:

```
public class JsonConverterAndroidOS implements IConvertToJson {
    @Override
    public String convertToJosn(Context ctx) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Log.i("", "gson.toJson(ctx) : " + gson.toJson(ctx));
    return gson.toJson(ctx);
    }
}
```

**code_2**:

```
this.mBtn_Start_GPS_Readings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS_READINGS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intentStartGPSService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GPSService.class);
            intentStartGPSService.setAction(ACTION_START_GPS_READING);

            //activity to json conversion
            IConvertToJson converter = new JsonConverterAndroidOS();
            String convertedToJson = converter.convertToJosn(MainActivity.this);
            intentStartGPSService.putExtra(KEY_MAIN_ACTIVITY_INSTANCE, convertedToJson);
            //startService(intentStartGPSService);
        }
    });
```

**error**:

```
2019-06-15 10:45:12.898 1983-2013/com.example.gps_v10 E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
2019-06-15 10:45:12.899 1983-2013/com.example.gps_v10 E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
2019-06-15 10:45:26.411 1983-1983/com.example.gps_v10 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.gps_v10, PID: 1983
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class android.content.res.ColorStateList declares multiple JSON fields named mChangingConfigurations
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:457)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:166)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:457)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:166)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:457)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:166)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:457)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:695)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:682)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:637)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:617)
    at com.example.gps_v10.JsonConverterAndroidOS.convertToJosn(JsonConverterAndroidOS.java:12)
    at com.example.gps_v10.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:49)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
2019-06-15 10:45:26.422 1983-1990/com.example.gps_v10 I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=30KB, data=26KB
2019-06-15 10:45:26.422 1983-1990/com.example.gps_v10 I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=30KB, data=26KB
2019-06-15 10:45:26.422 1983-1990/com.example.gps_v10 I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
```

Comment: paste your pojo/bean class where field is there " mChangingConfigurations"

Comment: Converting entire activity to JSON is not feasible. Intents only carry a small bundle of data, you must decide what you actually need to send to service and include it in intent extras.

Answer (score 3):

It looks you need context inside service, Therefore you are trying to convert Activity object to JSON object (as per my understanding).
The solution is just to use **this** keyword only inside service
`Context context = this;` because Service is made up of Context only, Maybe more details can help you [Get Context in a Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446221/get-context-in-a-service)